# I wonder a php 7.4 giving me trouble on login script

Tags: php, php-7.4

Problem is occurring when no user exists because PHP 7.4 returns `false` here on  `$fetched = $check->fetch();`

so how to handle this situation

```
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $check = $db->prepare("SELECT id, name, pass FROM users WHERE name = ?");
    $check->execute([$name]);
    $fetched = $check->fetch();
    if (password_verify($pass, $fetched['pass']) && ($name === $fetched['name']){
        header('Location: home');
    } else {
        echo 'This account not exists';
    }
```

but I don't know why this work without `password_verify()`, look

```
if ($check->rowCount() > 0 ) {

} else {

}
```

Comment: check if isset $fetched[pass] and than password verify

Comment: Plain text passwords and not sanitizing the input ...that's more holes than Swiss cheese has.

Comment: @MartinZeitler It's not plain-text passwords, it's using `password_verify()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a check for `$fetched`:

```
if ($fetched && password_verify($pass, $fetched['pass'])) {
    header('Location: home');
} else {
    echo "Invalid username or password";
}
```

There's no need to test `$fetch['name']`. It's guaranteed to be equal to `$name` because of `WHERE name = ?`